# SharePoint Online : Permission to list based on user

Tags: sharepoint-online, item-level-permissions

How can we setup list permission based on following scenario:
- Administrator and SP Group A should be able to see records of all users
- SP Group B should be able to see records where department = "ABC"
- Other users should be able to see only records where Manager = [ME]

We are using SharePoint online.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can manage this scenario using `Target Audience` as the following

- Besides `all items` view, Create additional two views, one filtered by Department and the other filtered by the manager.
- Create a page to show all three views,
- Add a list view web part, and select your current view.
- Repeat the above steps for each view.
- Edit the list view web part, and at **Target Audience** section, set your **group** name based on your requirements.